# Hibernate versioned schema generation on first application start?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

With indexeddb schema creation is done via a version variable like this:

```
// Database version.
var version = 1;

// Open a connection to the datastore.
var request = indexedDB.open('todos', version);
```

So if this is the first time the database is being created, then indexeddb will run `request.onupgradeneeded` to initialize the database schema.  If we want to upgrade it, then we simply bump the version.

If was wondering if Hibernate 5 has any similar capabilities, such that we can rely on it for schema generation the first time the application is run?

TIA,
Ole

Comment: Not entirely sure whether hibernate 5 has the requested functionality out of the box but http://www.liquibase.org/(Liquibase) has this functionality definitely. On top of it you can create upgrades automatically, etc. With some tweaking you can align it with your JPA/JDO annotated classes.

Comment: Sweet - I'll check out liquibase - thanks!